# Class definitions in static getter methods

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, javascript, object-oriented-design, node.js

[Node.js / CommonJS]

I'm creating a single GitHub repo for my tool which has a Core, Control, Server, and Client library. It's unlikely that all of them will be used at the same time.

I'd like my fellow coworkers to `require` one entry point for all four libraries. So I made this *questionable* implementation: exporting the Core class with static properties pointing to the other classes.

Tool.js

```
class Core
{
    static get Control(){return require("./control")};
    static get Server(){return require("./server")};
    static get Client(){return require("./client")};
    constructor(opts)
    {
    }
}
module.exports = Core;
// module.exports = {Core, Control, Server, Client};
```

index.js

```
//Create core instance
const Tool = require("Tool");
const tool = new Tool();

//Create server instance
const ToolServer = require("Tool").Server;

//etc
const ToolClient = require("Tool").Client;
```

Is this a bad pattern? I'd RTFM in regards to importing classes from static properties, but I'm not sure where to find resources that dives deep into the inner workings of JavaScript/Node.js/CommonJS.

Comment: I think I'm missing some of the magic in this code. How does `require()` learn to map `"Tool"` to `Core`?

Comment: @candied_orange Hi, `"Tool"` resolves to `"Tool.js"` or something like that. `Core` is the name of the class definition, not necessarily the filename.

Comment: are you telling me that the `Core` class is defined in `Tool.js`, and `require("Tool")` somehow knows `Core` is the only class to care about in there?

Comment: @candied_orange `require` takes whatever is assigned to `module.exports`... Edited for clarity.

Comment: if I use `module.exports = {Core, Core2}` and `require("Tool").Server;` which cores server do I get?

Comment: @candied_orange Neither. You get undefined. `{Core, Core2}` is shorthand for `{Core: Core, Core2: Core2}` which means you would need to do something like `require("Tool").Core2.Server` to get the Server class.

Comment: Yet `module.exports = Core;` and `require("Tool").Server;` will work fine together? No need to use `require("Tool").Core.Server;`?

Comment: @candied_orange Yup, you're directly assigning the `Core` class to `module.exports`, unlike the previous example which was assigning an object `{Core: Core}` instead. I suggest you read up on ES6/ESNext and CommonJS if you want to learn more about this.

Comment: Then if you spread `require("Tool").Server;` around you're forcing `module.exports` to always have only one entry.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems to me this works as a namespace, currently ES6 modules allow for something similar with the `export` and `import` keywords:

Core.js

```
import * as Control from './control';
import * as Server from './server';

export {Control, Server}
```

I've used that pattern in many projects and it always helps in keeping code modular.

The only thing I would change in your `require` implementation you could use an object instead of a `class`, that way is more readable and there are no functions involved, something like:

Core.js

```
const Control = require('./control');
const Server = require('./server');

module.exports = {Controle, Server};

// Another alternative would be

module.exports.Control = require('./control');
module.exports.Server = require('./server');
```

If you still want to do a lazy `require` as I assume for having functions, this could be an alternative:

```
module.exports = {
  Control = () => require('./control'),
  Server = () => require('./server')
}
```